# API/Web-service Methods Checking Software

Tags: web-services, testing

Is there any software, which we can use the test the API/Web-service methods? What I am looking for something like this.

1. I enter the url
2. Enter POST/GET parameters

and in return I get the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got what I was looking for.

http://hurl.it/

Hurl makes HTTP requests.
Enter a URL, set some headers, view the response, then share it with others.
Perfect for demo and debugging APIs.

Comment: A list of similar tools : http://stackoverflow.com/a/12637452/363573